# $\varnothing \subseteq A, \forall A$ What if $A = \varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was just wondering, we know that $\varnothing \subseteq A$ for all $A$ but what if $A = \varnothing$?

Then how does it make sense that $\varnothing \subseteq \varnothing$?

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with this?

Comment: every set is a subset of itself. to check $A \subset B$ you need to check that every element of $A$ is also in $B$. In the case of $\emptyset$ this is vacuously true - this set has no elements to verify this condition for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using Venn diagrams.  Draw a circle with nothing in it.  This represents the empty set.  Now draw another circle inside the circle you just drew.  This will show you that the empty set is a subset of the empty set.

Comment: If you draw another circle inside a circle then doesn't that imply that the larger circle contains an element? Which would mean that the empty set is not really empty?

Comment: No.  The circle simply indicates a boundary.  It does not indicate "things."

Comment: If the circle doesn't mean element then it must mean set right? and if not, then what does the circle mean exactly?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to give you a sense of what it means without going to axioms (as distinct from all the other answers you got).  So the circle really is just an abstract boundary.  The set is the collection of "things" inside the boundary.

Comment: Ahhh! I see what you mean now. Thanks! This is what I was looking for `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It does make sense, because for every set $A$ it is true that $A\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1):

Every element of the empty set is an element of the empty set. Is there a *particular* element of the empty set that is not an element of the empty set? Answer: no. Therefore, $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to think about it: could is be that $\varnothing$ is **not** a subset of $\varnothing$?

Well, to show that $A$ is not a subset of $B$, we would find a suitable element $x$, then confirm that it is in $A$ and not in $B$.

In the case we are looking at we do it as follows: take an element $x$; confirm that $x\in\varnothing$. . . oops. . . we don't even get started since $x$ can't be an element of $\varnothing$.

Therefore it is impossible that $\varnothing$ is **not** a subset of $\varnothing$, which means that $\varnothing$ **is** a subset of $\varnothing$.